# Excel timespan format like [d] hh:mm:ss?

Tags: excel, date, datetime, cell-formatting

In Excel, a numeric value can be displayed as a date and time, and one possibility is to show the number of hours as an arbitrarily large number (not modulo 24), followed by minutes and seconds the normal way. For example: `[h]:mm:ss` displays `956:45:32` for a value that corresponds to 956 hours, 45 minutes and 32 seconds.

I would like to have a similar format, but for days: `[d] hh:mm:ss`, where I would like `hh` to show hours modulo 24 as usual, but `[d]` to show any number of days. This doesn't work, as it seems. I can use `d hh:mm:ss` but that shows days modulo whole months, presumably starting with January. I.e. 32 days and 3 hours is displayed as `1 03:00:00`, while I would like to see `32 03:00:00`.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am not interested in VBA solutions, I just want a simple cell format.

Comment: Don't think that is possible with formatting.  You'll need a formula that creates a text string and displays the days and `hh;mm` separately. But then you won't be able to math operations on the value.

Comment: *...a simple cell format....* I don't think it's possible. When you use something like `d hh:mm:ss` , it's getting converted to a date, not a quantity of days. 32 days and 3 hours = 771 hours. If you type `771:00:00` in a cell and change the format to `dd mm yyyy` you will see that Excel returns `01/02/1900 Wednesday`. Because the day 32 from first one is, actually, `01/02/1900`. Excel is converting the quantity of hours to a specific date, not to a a quantity of days. That explains why it returns `1 03:00:00`. Because of this, I think it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks I'm aware what hapens. I still think it *should* be possible to format it with [d] anf get the result I want. I've posted it on User Voice.